# How do I create an event upon click prev/next? FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, fullcalendar

So far I have, clicking a day on the calendar in month view, will change the view to agendaDay which does a for loop to populate each time slot with an event. I want to do the same thing when I click prev or next. This is my attempt but it keeps crashing when I click prev. This part of the code is in fullcalendar.js

```
function prev() {
    date = currentView.computePrevDate(date);
    var myCalendar = $('myCalendar1');
    var yearClicked = date.format('YYYY');
    var yearClicked = parseInt(yearClicked);
    var monthClicked = date.format('MM');
    var monthClicked = parseInt(monthClicked) - 1;
    var dayClicked = date.format('DD');
    var dayClicked = parseInt(dayClicked);
    for(timeIncrement = 7; timeIncrement < 23; timeIncrement++){
        alert(date.format('MM'));
        var myEvent = {
            title: 'Rooms Available [' + 11 + ']',
            start: new Date(yearClicked, monthClicked, dayClick, timeIncrement),
            url: 'http://google.com'

        };
        myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent);

    }
    renderView();

}
```

Comment: can't see anything that would crash it. Do you get errors? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly* (it is very hard to tell without more context and code) the fact that you are creating `timeIncrement` and `date` as global variables (by not declaring them with var (or let in ES2015)) is an issue.

(You may well have explicitly declared `date` in some outer function, but that is not visible in your example, so I can only go on what I can see)

This may be causing conflicts with other parts of your code...